# Cargar un mensaje informativo tras otro transcurridos x segundos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tengo una parte de mi código que quisiera modificar. Estoy enviando a imprimir
 y muestro un mensaje, lo que quiero hacer es que tras 5 segundos me muestre otro mensaje informativo y que, tras 3 segundos más, desaparezca y siga el flujo del programa.

El código :

```html
    $(function() {
        renderTexts();
        renderButtons(['entrar','salir']);  

$("#boton-confirmar").get(0).clickCallback = function () {
            alert_UI('Aguarde un instante mientras se imprime el ticket', 'Imprimiendo', 'loading');
            return false;
        };
```

El mensaje que quiero se muestre tras 5 segundos y desaparezca tras 3 segundos sería:

```
alert_UI('Tome su ticket y entréguelo en ventanilla ', 'Canjes', 'loading');
```

He probado enlazar pero sin éxito. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Podrías explicar lo que significa _... y siga el flujo del programa_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Es tan sencillo como mostrar los mensajes dentro de `window#setTimeout`.

```
function alertUI(message, title, status, delayShow, delayHide) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    // mostrar mensaje
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      // esconder mensaje
    }, delayHide);
  }, delayShow);
}
```

Lo usarías así:

```
alert_UI('Tome su ticket y entréguelo en ventanilla ', 'Canjes', 'loading', 5000, 3000);
```

---

Respecto a:

> y siga el flujo del programa

En JavaScript no hay manera de "dormir" el thread como en otros lenguajes. Recuerda que JavaScript es un lenguaje asíncrono.

Comment: Hola buenísimo. Este es un fragmento de un programa que estoy retocando en mi actual trabajo. Originalmente lo hizo una empresa que cerró y entre las complicaciones, algunos php estan encriptados. 
Tengo 1 duda adicional :
alert_UI ya es una función que no se de donde la toma ( creo es una librería para mensajes que la carga al inicio) , si yo reescribo la función tal cual me pasaste pienso que me anulará otras llamadas que tengo en la misma página ?

Comment: No, la función que escribí actuará como "envoltorio" de la que ya tienes definida. En el `setTimeout` debes llamar a la función que tienes definida pasándole los parámetros.